# EM algorithm - What happens with the standard deviation?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, statistics

## What have you tried?

So I watched [this](https://youtu.be/iQoXFmbXRJA?t=419) video.
According to the video, we've to calculate the variance $\sigma^2$ as follows:
$$
    \sigma_{k}^{2} = 
    \frac
        {
            p_{1} \left(x_{1} - \mu_{k_1}\right)^{2} + \ldots + p_{n} \left(x_{n}
                - \mu_{k_n}\right)^{2}
        }
        {
            p_{1} + p_{2} + \ldots + p_{n}
        }
$$

Where

- $k$ is the index of the current Gaussian class.
- $p$ represents the possibility of one point of the set
- $n$ is the amount of points in the set

## So what's your question?

I don't understand, why we have to use $\mu_{1}$, $\mu_{2}$, $\ldots$,
$\mu_{n}$. I expected to calculate it follows:
$$
    \sigma_{k}^{2} = 
    \frac
        {
            p_{1} \left(x_{1} - \mu_k\right)^{2} + \ldots + p_{n} \left(x_{n}
                - \mu_k\right)^{2}
        }
        {
            p_{1} + p_{2} + \ldots + p_{n}
        }
$$

Because why do I have to use the "current-calculated" mean of the Gaussian and
not the "final" one?

Comment: At the very time point in the video that your link takes you the speaker mentions that there is a typo.

Comment: Oooh, so he means that the `1` in the first mean is a mistake or does he mean a different typo?

Comment: Ok, so my program seems to work now (half). Thank you for this hint! Can you write your comment as an answer so I can mark this question as "answered"?

Comment: @plop Please write an answer so that this question is not left unanswered.

Comment: @plop (in case if you forgot it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer of @plop:

> At the very time point in the video that your link takes you the speaker mentions that there is a typo.

Comment: Please write the actual answer in this space, not just a claim that the answer exists elsewhere.  You can credit the original comment by linking to it if you like.

Comment: thank you for the hint. I edited my answer.